# fill array with random numbers in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays

How can i fill array with around 500 random number in objective-c , the below code get the random numbers from 1 to 200 but how can i fill them in array i need afterwords to do some calculations on them

```
    int i,x;
NSArray *myArray;
for (x=1; x<100; x++) {
    i = (arc4random()%200)+1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to use arrays?

Comment: You need to open a book and learn how arrays work.  There's no sense in someone just giving you the code.  You won't learn anything and on the very next operation, you'll be right here asking.  Do some study and then if you still have questions, you should be able to post code that's at least in the ballpark and only needs minor assistance.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
   NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
     [array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];

   /* Use array */
}
```